# PDF not opening in my browser in production

Tags: html, pdf

I have a Razor MVC application that contains a link to open a PDF stored on a file server. My code works when I run it in Visual Studio but is not working when I try it on production on the same computer. I click the link and nothing happens, I can see the path when I hover over it though. There are no errors or anything.  I've tried all browsers but only really care about IE.

```
 <a href="\\01erie\Q\Data\Company Sharded Folder\MSDS\PVC567.pdf">View</a>
```

Image when I hover over the link

[image]

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: Have you tried the proper syntax, i.e. `file://///01erie....`? As per comments [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767731). On Firefox and Chrome [this isn't possible at all](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_don%27t_work), though, it could be that IE has followed suit

Comment: I tried `<a href="file://///01erie/Q/Data/Company Shared Folder/MSDS/PVC567.pdf">View</a>` with the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filesystem URLs from remote pages (i.e. pages on other protocols like `http://` or even other directories in the file system) are blocked by modern browsers for security reasons.

[Here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_don%27t_work) is a page describing the behaviour for Firefox (along with reasons why it exists).

Internet Explorer has [joined the ranks of these modern browsers:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee330731(v=vs.85).aspx#file_protocol_nav)

> By default, Internet Explorer prevents navigation to Uniform Resource
> Identifiers (URIs) using the "file:" protocol when the current URL
> matches the following conditions:
>
> - The current URL is opened in the Internet zone or the Restricted Sites zone.
> - The current URL uses a protocol other than "file:".
>
> This is a security measure designed to
> prevent malicious sites from accessing system file objects.

This can be changed, but only on a per-client basis (see the MSDN article for details.)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond!